# AppendTo a div by id programmatically in Google apps script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-apps-script, google-sites

I'm trying to build a drop menu where the content is filled with data from a database. I have this working in plain html/jquery, but it doesn't work in a Google apps script.

Code :

```
function buildDropDown(inTitle, inName, inMenuId, inFilterId, inArray)
{
    // Create the drop down menu
    var div = $('<div id="' + inMenuId + '" class="funnelFiltermenu">');
    var input = $('<input type="text" name="' + inName + '" value="All" class="field" readonly />').appendTo(div);
    var ul = $('<ul class="funnelFilterlist">').appendTo(div);

    // Add the items of the drop down menu
    $.each(inArray, function(index,item) {
        $(ul).append('<li>'+item+'</li>')
    });

    // Add the drop down menu to the funnel
    $( div).appendTo(".dropdown");
}
```

This works outside of Google script. It does not work in the Google apps script. I guess this has something to do with the caja stuff. So I changed the code so it would look for classes which then looks like:

```
function buildDropDown(inTitle, inName, inMenuId, inFilterId, inArray)
{
    // Create the drop down menu
    var div = $('<div id="' + inMenuId + '" class="funnelFiltermenu">');
    $( div).appendTo(".dropdown");
    var theId = app.getElementById(div);

    var input = $('<input type="text" name="' + inName + '" value="All" class="field" readonly />').appendTo(theId);
    var ul = $('<ul class="funnelFilterlist">').appendTo(".funnelFiltermenu");

    // Add the items of the drop down menu
    $.each(inArray, function(index,item) {
        $(".funnelFilterlist").append('<li>'+item+'</li>')
    });
}
```

Since there will be more than one drop down (with the same classes), I cannot use classes. I'll have to use Ids instead. But caja changes the Id.

Any thoughts on how to approach this?

Comment: When working with element IDs, `$("#elementId")` should just work as expected in jQuery. Please don't worry about Caja.

Comment: Since the IDs are generated client side <div id="' + inMenuId + '" I think there is an issue with Caja. The code works outside of the script, but not in the script.

Comment: I have a work around now where I hard code most of the elements and just add the <li> portion through jQuery.

html
`<div id="dropdown2" class="dropdown">
    <div id="dd2" class="funnelFiltermenu">
    <input type="text" name="aansturing" value="<?= getProjectData(2, 5) ?>" class="field" readonly />
    <ul id="ul2" class="funnelFilterlist"></ul>
    </div>
</div>`

jQuery
`// Add the items of the drop down menu
$.each(gInitiatief, function(index,item) {
    $("#ul2").append('<li>'+item+'</li>')
});`

Answer (score 0):

I have created the following work around:

I hard coded more elements in the html code:

```
<div class="SSCheader"><h1>Project Eigenschappen</h1></div>
<div class="SSCcontent">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Project Nr</b></td>
                <td><?= getProjectData(2, 1) ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Project Initiatief</b></td>
                <td>
                    <div id="dropdown2" class="dropdown">
                        <div id="dd2" class="funnelFiltermenu">
                            <input type="text" name="aansturing" value="<?= getProjectData(2, 5) ?>" class="field" readonly />
                            <ul id="ul2" class="funnelFilterlist"></ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Primair domein</b></td>
                <td>
                    <div id="dropdown3" class="dropdown">
                        <div id="dd3" class="funnelFiltermenu">
                            <input type="text" name="aansturing" value="<?= getProjectData(2, 6) ?>" class="field" readonly />
                            <ul id="ul3" class="funnelFilterlist"></ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Aansturing door</b></td>
                <td>
                    <div id="dropdown4" class="dropdown">
                        <div id="dd4" class="funnelFiltermenu">
                            <input type="text" name="aansturing" value="<?= getProjectData(2, 7) ?>" class="field" readonly />
                            <ul id="ul4" class="funnelFilterlist"></ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And only add the

in javascript:

```
var gDomains = ["Rapportage", "Relaties", "Leden", "Projecten", "Personeel", "Boekhouding", "Faciliteren", "Verkoop", "Inkoop"];
var gInitiatief = ["SSC", "BIP", "ICCO", "C&F", "IO", "FZ", "KIA", "KIO", "JOP", "MWK", "HRM"];
var gAansturing = ["RegieOverleg", "Beleidstafel", "Lijnmanagement", "Stuurgroep"];


// Add the items of the drop down menu
$.each(gInitiatief, function(index,item) {
    $("#ul2").append('<li>'+item+'</li>')
});

// Add the items of the drop down menu
$.each(gDomains, function(index,item) {
    $("#ul3").append('<li>'+item+'</li>')
});

// Add the items of the drop down menu
$.each(gAansturing, function(index,item) {
    $("#ul4").append('<li>'+item+'</li>')
});
```

I think that because the IDs are now hard coded, the problem is no longer there.